# Compare 2 excel file using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, compare

I was just wondering if is there any way of comparing two excels spreadsheets using macro. I have a piece of macro that basically does the work but it checks column by column. So say in case I have a value defined in `A(1,1)` in `sheet1` and if the same value is not present in `A(1,1)` in `sheet2` but the value present in any row of the column then it won't raise a complaint.

```
'compare Sheet
Sub CompareTable()
Dim tem, tem1 As String
Dim text1, text2 As String
Dim i As Integer, hang1 As Long, hang2 As Long, lie As Long, maxhang As Long, maxlie As Long
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Rows("1:" & lastRow).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    maxhang = lastRow       ' number of the last row containg data
    MaxRow = lastRow
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    MaxColumn = LastCol
    For col = 1 To MaxColumn
        For hang1 = 2 To maxhang
            Dim a As Integer
            a = 0
            tem = Sheets(1).Cells(hang1, col)
            For hang2 = 1 To maxhang
                tem1 = Sheets(2).Cells(hang2, col)
                If tem1 = tem Then
                a = 1
                Sheets(2).Cells(hang2, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                For lie = 1 To maxlie
                    text1 = Sheets(1).Cells(hang1, lie)
                    text2 = Sheets(2).Cells(hang2, lie)
                    If text1 <> text2 Then
                    Sheets(2).Cells(hang2, lie).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                    End If
                Next
                End If
            Next

            If a = 0 Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(hang1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note :** I'm looking for any solution that could give me a row match,  so if any value of the given row is not matched with the sheet2 then it should highlight it.

I'm open to have any other alternative as well. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: So if `A1-->Cell(1,1)` is not found in any Row1, then the code should highlight `A1-->Cell(1,1)`;If `B1-->Cell(2,1)` is found in Row2 then should't highlight it. Is my Understanding right?

Comment: Are else are you looking for a one to one mapping? Like `Sheet1-A1`-->`Sheet2-A1`,`Sheet1-A2`-->`Sheet2-A2`,...`Sheet1-B1`-->`Sheet2-B1`..

Comment: So basically what is my requirement is, I have to match an entire row say 1st row of `sheet1` with 1st row of `sheet2` and so on. I want to compare both the files row by row. But what my current code is doing is checking each value of `sheet1`  with columns in `sheet2`, so the problem is if `A(1,2)` has value `A` in `sheet1` and `A(1,5)` has `A` in `sheet 2` then it is not highlighting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you are expecting. Please see my below code

```
Sub CompareTable()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Dim table1 As Range
    Dim table2 As Range

    Dim table1Rows As Integer
    Dim table1Cols As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set table1 = ws1.Cells
    Set table2 = ws2.Cells

    table1Rows = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    table1Cols = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To table1Rows
        For j = 1 To table1Cols
            If table1(i, j).Value = table2(i, j).Value Then
            Else
            ws1.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Sheet1 table
[image]
Sheet2 table
[image]

After Running the code tgisis my result

[image]